# Objective-C : Synchronizing code

Tags: objective-c, synchronization, nsmutablearray, grand-central-dispatch

I have a simple class with two ivars, a `NSMutableArray` and a `BOOL`. Objects of this class are able to shuffle elements in the array when they are sent the `startShuffling` message. They do so until they receive the `stopShuffling` message.

To make it work, the `startShuffling` method set the boolean to `YES`, and then dispatch the block of code that shuffles (`while(self.isShuffling) { //... }` on a concurrent queue. The `stopShuffling` set the boolean to `NO`, so that the shuffling process will terminate on the next loop turn.

Here is the interface :

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject <NSCoding> {
@private
    NSMutableArray *elements_;
    __block BOOL isShuffling_;
}

@property(readonly) BOOL isShuffling;

-(void)startShuffling;
-(void)stopShuffling;

@end
```

And the implementation :

```
@implementation MyClass

@synthesize isShuffling = isShuffling_;

-(void)startShuffling {
    if(self.isShuffling) {
        return;
    }

    isShuffling_ = YES;

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        while(isShuffling_) {
            // code that shuffles, one element by turn
            NSUInteger elementIndex = arc4random() % [elements_ count];
            id c = [[elements_ objectAtIndex:elementIndex] retain];
            [elements_ removeObjectAtIndex:elementIndex];
            [elements_ insertObject:c atIndex:[elements_ count]];
            [c release];
        }
    });
}

-(void)stopShuffling {
    isShuffling_ = NO;
}

@end
```

My class conforms to `NSCoding` protocol and I don't want to abort encoding even if the object is shuffling. Instead I want my object to stop shuffling and then encode itself. So I have written this encoding method :

```
-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {
    if(self.isShuffling) {
        [self stopShuffling];
    }
    [aCoder encodeObject:elements_ forKey:kIVPCodingKeyMyClassElements];
}
```

Finally, here my question.
I think it is possible for the `encodeObject:forKey:` method to get called while the shuffling loop terminates its last turn (maybe I'm wrong ?).

Is there any way I can make `encodeObject:forKey:` method <strike>get called *after*</strike> wait for the shuffling loop last turn to terminate ?

Comment: dispatch_sync() won't help on a global concurrent queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the the shuffle code may still be running when the `encodeObject:forKey:` method is called.

In general, you don't want to dispatch some random block off onto a queue that executes for a really long time, potentially forever.   You want to break up the work into blocks of work.   And there-in lies your answer.

Something like:

```
 - (void)shuffleAndCheck
 {
    if (stillShuffling) {
         dispatch_async(globalConcurrentQueue, ^{
              dispatch_apply(shuffleQueue, ^{... shuffle one card code ...});
         });
         dispatch_async(shuffleQueue, ^{ [self shuffleAndCheck]; });
    }
 }

 - (void) startShuffling
 {
    if (stillShuffling) return;
    stillShuffling = YES;
    [self shuffleAndCheck];
 }

 - (void) stopShuffling
 {
    stillShuffling = NO;
    dispatch_async(shuffleQueue, ^{ ... encode stuff here ... });
 }
```

Or something.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still have doubts, I understand that the `^{ ... encode stuff here ... }` block will be executed *after* all the shuffling blocks, but the object seems to initiate the encoding process itself here, and my object could receive the `encodeWithCoder:` message at any time. Or maybe you meant *caching* the array by "encode stuff here".

Comment: I can dispatch the block on the `shuffleQueue` in my `encodeWithCoder:` method however. But is that right to do so asynchronously ? I would have done this rather synchronously, to make the `encode...:` method waiting for the block to complete before returning.

Comment: You could either use a callback or dispatch synchronously.  As long as you don't dispatch from the shuffleQueue, no harm done.   Personally, I would go with an async dispatch from the "encode stuff here" block back to whatever queue you need.   You can effectively treat that as synchronous in your UI if you want and if you ever want it to be asynchronous, it already is.

Comment: I have broken the "random block" into smaller ones as you suggested, dispatched on a serial queue that is an ivar of my class, this works perfectly. The `stopShuffling` method now "waits" for the shuffle to end, by dispatching an empty block *synchronously* on the serial shuffle queue, and it seems to work too. Now in every other method of the class I can call it and be sure that no element swapping is happening. Thank you for your suggestions.